# How to make f:ajax ignore invalid ids in render attribute?

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2, ajax4jsf

I am creating JSF components in back-end. Also, ajax support is added using AjaxBehavior.

```
AjaxBehavior a4jSupport = (AjaxBehavior) app.createBehavior(AjaxBehavior.BEHAVIOR_ID);
List<String> updateIds = getUpdateIds();
if (updateIds !=null){
    a4jSupport.setRender(updateIds);
    ((UIComponentBase) component).addClientBehavior("change", a4jSupport);
}
```

Idea is to add re-render set of components when value changes for certain input component. I am facing issue when any of the update id coming is invalid. It throws Javax.faces.FacesException mentioning that a particular id is invalid.

Need to know, if there is any way that invalid ids can be ignored rather than throwing up exceptions?

Comment: I think the main purpose of the exception is to catch it and handle the unexpected result, in other words when you catch it you can ignore it.

Comment: Thats the main issue over here... This is coming while UI gets rendered. I am not too sure about how to catch this one as everything executes just fine on server side. Its only when component gets rendered in UI, this exception gets thrown up.

Comment: Just to add to the above comment, I think this needs to be handled in renderResponse phase but not too sure of the way to cleanly handle this.